# for each loop not hitting the GET api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop

Here i am getting the list of medicines

```
 $scope.initStarttoGetDrugs = function () {
          $http({
          url: '/MedicineParserApp/getmedicinefromdb',
        method: "GET", 
            }).success(function(response){
          $rootScope.MedicinneName = response;
          var medlength = response.length;
          response.forEach(function(listItem, index){
         $scope.keyup(listItem) // here i want to hit the api
          });
      });
            };
          $scope.initStarttoGetDrugs();
```

here on console it is going to url but not hitting the api and not giving the response

```
  $scope.keyup = function (data) {
   $http({
    url: 'https://www.example.com/medicineinfo/search?q='+data,
    method: "GET", 
        }).success(function(response){
            console.log(response)
        $scope.results = response.data;
        $rootScope.vars = $scope.results 
        console.log($rootScope.vars);
        for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
             $scope.onclickfetchinfo($scope.results[i].slug, $scope.results[i].id)
        }
             });
       };
```

Please let me know why this is happing and what is the solution

edit : used settimeout but still not working;

Answer (score 0):

This is because your request is cached. Always send a new url to server.
    url: 'https://www.example.com/medicineinfo/search?/?x=" + new Date().getTime(),